# What kind or kinds of beer are common in Bavaria, Germany?

Tags: local, german-beers

I visited Bavaria Germany once and had my first taste of beer ever.  It was delicious!  I have no idea what beer or even what type of beer it was.

I've since "sampled extensively" many beers in my home area ( Minnesota, USA ) but whenever I look through a liquor store, I never see "Bavarian Beer" on any labels.  I sometimes see "Belgian" and get that by mistake, but I usually don't like those ones, haha.

Looking suggestions of beer type or specific brands or flavors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was said before, a Weissbier is also called a Hefeweizen and is very common in Bavaria and the rest of Germany.  If you want something similiar look for a Paulaner Hefeweizen which is sold in America.  The yeast that is added gives it a strong Banana like flavor.  It is typically served in a tall narrow glass.

Other common beers in Bavaria are Oktoberfest, Pilsner, Doppelbock, and Dunkel. Out of those the Pilsner and Oktoberfest don't have a ton a flavor.  The other two have sweeter flavors and are darker with the Doppelbock being available in the winter as a high alcohol beer.

Very few labels will specify Bavaria, but all imported beers are required by law to specify their country of origin. Bavarian Beers(or Biers if you will) are the same as other German beers, so simply look for a German beer.

Answered by: The Gastrograph Team

Comment: Thank you, some names you mentioned look familiar, so I should be able to find a bunch to try!

Comment: Lots of US craft breweries make wonderful hefeweizens too.  If it was darker, it might have been a dunkelweizen.

Answer (score 2):

Was the beer that you tried pale yellow, slightly sour in flavour and cloudy? If so it was probably Weissbier which is Bavarian wheat based beer. Any Weissbier or wheat beer should be similar to it and these are widely available (some British and American breweries have started to make wheat beers recently). If you like Weissbier you will probably like the Saison (style) beers from France and Belguim.

It the beer was dark coloured it was probably the **highly seasonal** and delicious Bockbier which is extremely difficult to get outside Bavaria and out of season.

Comment: I was a long time ago now, but I think it was darker.  Pretty sure it wasn't on the sour end, as I didn't like most beer when I was "new to beer" and I still don't like IPA style beer ( though I'll drink it occasionally ).  I want to say it was sweeter, but not sure.  Mostly just looking for things to try from that area.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for brands, you find a List of Bavarian breweries on [Wikipedia.](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Brauereien_in_Bayern)

The page is in German, but due to the fact that you are interested in the brand names, this should also work if you don't speak any German.

Comment: I would also suggest visiting a local German restaurant.  The good ones will have a number of German beers on hand.  I'm sure the person who asked the question could find lots of German restaurants up in Minnesota.